# Server methods outside of Meteor.methods

Tags: meteor

On the client I need a helper method that returns true or false depending on whether the user is eligible for a payment request.

However, I can't really use a Meteor.method for this, because they don't return a value on the client.

Instead, I have done this and would like to know if this poses any security holes or if there is a preferable approach

Server:

```
...
// Constants
//
_.extend(Payments, {
  MINIMUM_REQUIRED_FOR_REQUEST: 100
});

// Public
//
Meteor.methods({
});

canRequestPayment = function(userId) {
  var user = Meteor.users.findOne(userId, { fields: { earnings: 1 } });
  if (_.isUndefined(user)) { throw new Meteor.Error('user-not-found', 'User not found'); }

  return hasEnoughCreditForRequest(user) && hasNoPendingPayments(user);
};

// Private
//
var hasNoPendingPayments = function(user) {
  return Payments.find({ userId: user._id, state: 'pending' }).count() === 0;
};

var hasEnoughCreditForRequest = function(user) {
  var period = user.earnings.period;
  return period >= Payments.MINIMUM_REQUIRED_FOR_REQUEST;
};
```

As can be seen, I have created two helper methods with `var`, to mimic private behavior, and then I have the `canRequestPayment` method which is accessable outside of the file, and that I call on the client instead of a Meteor.method

Client:

```
Template.payments.helpers({

  eligibleForPaymentRequest: function() {
    return canRequestPayment(Meteor.userId());
  },
```

Comment: Can you explain the phrase "because they don't return a value on the client"? Methods can return a value  - it's the second parameter of the asynchronous callback. See [this](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_call) for more details.

Comment: You cant do something like var somevar = Meteor.call()... it will return undefined

Comment: Correct - it's asynchronous. So like all things asynchronous, you can still get the value, you just have to do some work. E.g. set a session variable in the callback and read it elsewhere.

Comment: But say I dont want a session variable, and want to be able to reuse the method on both the client and server

Comment: So doing something like `Meteor.call('confirmEligibility', function(err, result) { if(result === true) doStuff(); });` is completely impossible?

Comment: No because the meteor call is async, when the template is rendered, the meteor call hasnt returned yet